# servo motor for 300gm of weight

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm working on an arduino project that comprises a basic arm (made out of cardboard or something). The goal is to simulate the action of the arm when a person is walking. However, I also want the arm to lift my mobile phone during the motion. The weight of the mobile is approx. 250gm. Which servo motor shall be the best to lift that amount of weight?
Currently I'm using the Tower Pro SG90 and it is not able to lift the weight. I've come across MG995 and MG946R. Which of these two would be suffice for this little project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mechanics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

The MG995 has a Torque of 10kg/cm at 6V, so it all depends on the length of your "arm".
so at 10cm it should still be able to lift around 1kg (you should divide that value by 3 to be safe) and you have to know that this 10kg torque is calculated when the an is horizontal, and a 10kg weight is attached with a string to the servo.

The MG946R is a bit stronger.

Very important is to provide sufficient power to the servos, the Arduino is not able to provide enough power for a servo motor, use e.g. a Servo Shield